# Fingerprint identification (1:N) for Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fingerprint

I am currently working on a project that utilizes a fingerprint scanner on a Chainway C71 Android device. The scanner is:

- Sensor: TCS1/TCS2 Capacitive
- Sensing Area (mm): 12.8×18; 10.4x14.4
- Resolution (dpi): 508 dpi, 8-bit greylevel
- Certifications: FIPS 201, STQC
- Format Extraction: ISO 19794, WSQ, ANSI 378, JPEG2000

I have two questions to ask you.

1. Has anyone here worked with this device, fingerprint scanner and
   hopefully its Xamarin SDK? Or its Android SDK - it doesn't matter -
   all I need is the principle of work and some explanation on how do you do (if it is possible at all) 1:N matching (i.e. identification)
2. If not with this device, has anyone used a Xamarin library that can do this matching for me? What I need is to have a functionality that gets a CurrentFingerprint pattern (usually a byte[]), a list of previously scanned patterns (list of people's fingerprints) and returns the person (ID from the list) that matches the input pattern.

Please, any information on 1:N matching on Xamarin is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. OK, I got in touch with Chainway's support. It appears that this device's fingerprint module can do 1:N identification, BUT only within 50 enrolled on that very device fingerprint scans. In other words you can't have your templates somewhere else and "load" them to the device for identification. You have to had previously enrolled each and every one of those 50 fingers one by one on that device and then be given an ID 0..49. Then the identification would return NotIdentified or a number from 0..49. It works quite fast, actually.
2. Any information on the second topic is welcome! But I will post another question, since it is not concerning the Chainway C71 anymore.